# I can't view separate files of repository in redmine if repo dir is a symbolic link

Tags: apache, hyperlink, http-status-code-404, redmine, repository

I can't view separate files of repository in redmine if repo dir is a symbolic link.

My repositories path: /mnt/datafs/repos

Redmine installed in /mnt/datafs/redmine. I.e. /mnt/datafs/config, ../../app, etc

I have a symlink

lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   17 Oct 16 10:41 repos -> /mnt/datafs/repos/

I cannot view a separate file in commit via redmine web, when repository path in a mysql database is /mnt/datafs/redmine/repos

If I change path in db to /mnt/datafs/repos then all is working.

Else I receive an error in browser:

The entry or revision was not found in the repository.

NOTE: View of repository is already working. I can't view only files contents.

Apache error log is empty.
Redmine production log is:

```
Started GET 
"/projects/credmine/repository/revisions/3ab72e21bbbe/entry/attributes/default.rb" for 
192.168.128.68 at 2013-10-15 16:07:22 +0400 Processing by RepositoriesController#entry as 
HTML Parameters: {"id"=>"credmine", "rev"=>"3ab72e21bbbe", 
"path"=>"attributes/default.rb"} Current user: skubriev (id=28) Rendered 
common/error.html.erb within layouts/base (0.2ms) Completed 404 Not Found in 219ms (Views: 
46.7ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
```

Comment: I think this one might belong in [serverfault](http://serverfault.com), since it's a professional system?

Comment: May be. Waiting for some response from other participants.

Comment: The answer is probably faster if you use the correct site. ;)